# Custom HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android

As the title says, I would like to create a custom HorizontalScrollView. My HSV will not have a scrollbar, but will have arrows on the sides. So, if there is something to be scrolled in the right side, the right arrow will be displayed. Otherwise it will be invisible.
My problem is that I need a listener for the HSV so that I am aware when there's nothing to be scrolled. Otherwise I don't know when to set the arrows states.
What would be the best approach for this feature?

Comment: will the arrows be ImageButtons or just graphical elements that will be drawn in onDraw()?

Comment: In 'ScrollView', there are two methods: 'http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#computeVerticalScrollOffset()' and 'http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#computeVerticalScrollRange()'. Can you subclass and use?